# Magento error code: 2140863473, there has been an error processing your request.

Tags: magento, wamp

oke so a few days ago i did a fresh install of Magento because i needed a safe testing environment. Because i already have a Magento system running i made a sql file of the database and tried uploading it. I needed to increase the max-upload since the file was too big for the limit. That is the only thing i've changed since installing. Now for my problem. When i try to get on the magento page i get the error message: There has been an error processing your request, with the error code: 2140863473. Now i've googled a bit about this problem and i found that one solution would be to edit something in the error file. Which i did. This is what i got after that:

```
> There has been an error processing your request SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045]
> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
> 
> Trace:
> #0 E:\Wamp\wamp\www\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
> #1 E:\Wamp\wamp\www\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(320): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
> #2 E:\Wamp\wamp\www\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(459): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
> #3 E:\Wamp\wamp\www\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
> #4 E:\Wamp\wamp\www\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
> #5 E:\Wamp\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource.php(169):
> Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
> #6 E:\Wamp\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource.php(110):
> Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql',
> Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
> #7 E:\Wamp\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(320):
> Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
> #8 E:\Wamp\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(350):
> Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
> #9 E:\Wamp\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(335):
> Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
> #10 E:\Wamp\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Cache.php(53):
> Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
> #11 E:\Wamp\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Cache.php(478):
> Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache->getAllOptions()
> #12 E:\Wamp\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Cache.php(520):
> Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
> #13 E:\Wamp\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1183):
> Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
> #14 E:\Wamp\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(414):
> Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
> #15 E:\Wamp\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(294):
> Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
> #16 E:\Wamp\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(413):
> Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
> #17 E:\Wamp\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343):
> Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
> #18 E:\Wamp\wamp\www\magento\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
> #19 E:\Wamp\wamp\www\magento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
> #20 {main}
> 
> Error log record number: 2140863473
```

if anyone has any idea about this problem feel free to share your thoughts.

PS. Im using Wamp to host the magento installation since i have no intention of actually launching the system. (since it's just for testing)

Comment: please check you database details in local.xml from app>etc>local.xml

Answer (score 0):

Please check two things:

1. Open app/etc/local.xml and check that database credentials are correct (must match with new DB credentials)
2. Access database and open **core_config_data** table, and check that values of:

   web/unsecure/base_url

and

```
web/secure/base_url
```

are correct or not.

Comment: After chaninng the values in the local.xml i get the error message: Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons, and a different error log number every time i refresh the page.

Comment: check /var/report folder.

there you can find error file with log number with complete trace of error.

Comment: Yes i understand but the thing is everytime i refresh the page i get a different error log record number. So pretty much every error log applies.

Comment: If you want to see error details in browser, just go to errors folder and rename local.xml.sample to local.xml